# How to fix 'Error 503 cdn error' while fetching from reddit api?

Tags: api, go, reddit

for learning purposes I'm building a command line tool using golang,
this cli fetches the top ten posts from **GameDeals** subreddit using the following api:

https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedeals/hot.json?limit=10

When I send the request I got as response a **503 Service Unavailable** and some HTML:

```html
<img src=//s3.amazonaws.com/redditstatic/heavy-load.png alt="">
<h2>Our CDN was unable to reach our servers</h2>
Please check <a href="http://www.redditstatus.com/">www.redditstatus.com</a> if you consistently get this error.
```

I don't understand why if I fires the request from a browser I got the json expected and instead a 503 error from my cli.

Here's my code that performs the request:

```golang
    address := fmt.Sprintf("%s/hot.json?limit=%d", redditBaseURL, 10)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("get", address, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", userAgent)

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()

    result, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Println(string(result))
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried to set the user agent like my browser but still got the 503

Comment: You cannot "fix" and upstream server error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, why from the browser I can get the json?

Comment: If you can reliably fetch the resource via your browser than just redo the exact same request in Go, including all headers, cookies, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed from https to http and now is working